# One of us carries a shield

Tags: knowledge, story, geography

> Hi, I'm Jackie. I'm pretty sure you know me already, but in any case it's nice to meet in person. I'd like to talk a little bit about my little group.
>
> I wouldn't call myself our leader in any real sense, but I certainly am our oldest member. We used to have more members, but currently it's only five of us with full membership. In addition we have many junior members, most of whom are children of full members.
>
> Now, some info about us. I won't bother describing myself – I'm pretty prominent so you're probably familiar with how I look like. I will say that I have a lot of children, and many of them are junior members in our group.
>
> As for the others, I'll tell you that one of them carries a shield with him. He's by no means a soldier, though, and you can tell that just by looking at his shield.
>
> Another member carries a picture of himself with him, although it's pretty well disguised and at first glance you'd think that it's something else entirely.
>
> Two of the others carry crosses, but don't think it's because they're religious. It's more of a symbol of where they're from than anything else. One of them has been thinking about leaving our little group, but I think he's decided to stay for now. It's his decision either way, of course.

Who are we?

Hint:

> For fun, I asked the other four members what their favourite colour was. It seems each of them likes some shade of blue.

Hint #2:

> Three of us carry stars.

Comment: Is it just me, or does Captain America become the first one to mind at the mention of "shield"? But we know he's a soldier... if only he wasn't... hmmm :\

Comment: Yup my first thought was the Avengers lol @user477343

Comment: One of us carries a S.H.I.E.L.D?

Comment: Lol Yeah, that was what I thought @jafe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are ...

> ... the flags that have the Union Flag of the United Kingdom in them.

In more detail:

> [image: Gang of Five]
>
>
>  The founding member Jackie is the Union flag of the United Kingdom, which is often called Union Jack. (The reference to the UK was already found out early on and nearly all other answers have it.)
>
>  The five members of the group are the flags of the UK, Australia, New Zealand, Fiji and Tuvalu. Some dependent states and territories of these states use similar designs in their flags. These states were at one time part of the British Empire and after gaining independence kept flags based on the Blue Ensign. Hawaii's flag also features the Union flag.
>
>  Some states had such flags at first, but have changed it; the most prominet one is probably Canada. Other states, such as Australia and New Zealand, are considering or have considered to change their flags. (I think there was a referendum to change the flag to a silver fern branch on black in New Zealand last year or something, but it was rejected.)
>
>  Of the five, the flag of Fiji is the one with the shield, which features agricultural designs and a peace dove. The flags of Australia, New Zealand and Tuvalu have stars. The flags of Australia and New Zealand show the constellation of the Southern Cross. Tuvalu is an archipelago and its flag indicates the position of its islands with stars, which looks more like a constallation than a map of the islands. The flags of Australia and New Zealand are dark blue, the flags of Fiji and Tuvalu are light blue, so they all like some shade of blue. And, of course, the Union Flag itself has blue in it.

Comment: This is it. Well done!

Answer (score 3):

You are

> Great Britain/UK (Union Jack/Jackie).  Your children are your former colonies.  The group is NATO

one of them carries a shield with him.

> The United States, whose shield contains olive branches, symbol of peace

Another member carries a picture of himself with him, although it's pretty well disguised and at first glance you'd think that it's something else entirely.

> Not sure on this one

Two of the others carry crosses, but don't think it's because they're religious. It's more of a symbol of where they're from than anything else.

> Norway, Iceland and Denmark have crosses on their flag

One of them has been thinking about leaving our little group

> Trump has made this threat about the US leaving

Comment: In this case the name, "Jackie," is very appropriate

Comment: But your group has 29 members, not 5

Comment: my first thought was rot13(gur HA Frphevgl pbhapvy, jvgu 5 zrzoref, ohg pbhyqa'g znxr vg svg.)

Comment: the one carrying the shield is "by no means a soldier"... which makes your answer arguable...

Answer (score 3):

Alright, so it seems obvious that Jackie, the first member, is

> the UK, as in the Union Jack

I wouldn't call myself our leader in any real sense, but I certainly am our oldest member. We used to have more members, but currently it's only five of us with full membership. In addition we have many junior members, most of whom are children of full members.

> the children are the colonies, the group is the commonwealth

As for the others, I'll tell you that one of them carries a shield with him. He's by no means a soldier, though, and you can tell that just by looking at his shield

> This is what makes me doubt my answer, there are many commonwealth-nation flags with shields - the blue helps tho. Blue, non-threatening (i.e. not a soldier) shield-bearing flags include: Belize, Saint Helena, Montserrat, Falklad Islands, British Virgin Islands and Anguilla. The other one is probably my best guess, the Catman Islands, as the shield shows three stars (second hint says three flags have stars)

Another member carries a picture of himself with him, although it's pretty well disguised and at first glance you'd think that it's something else entirely.

> I don't know much about the chronology of colonies, but based on the hint that they all like blue - the Bahamas flag represents the sand (yellow) and the Caribbean (blue),Saint Lucia's flag has similar colour symbolism, as well as the triangles representing the iconic Pitons, two volcanic mountains (that's a pretty good 'picture of himself')

Two of the others carry crosses, but don't think it's because they're religious. It's more of a symbol of where they're from than anything else. One of them has been thinking about leaving our little group, but I think he's decided to stay for now. It's his decision either way, of course.

> Australia and New Zealand carry the Southern Cross on their flags, which is visible in the southern hemisphere, where they are. Australia has thought of leaving before (1999 and recently) but benefits too much from the commonwealth.

This is my best guess, but I will edit as I go.

Comment: I think you're bang on and was about to write this answer myself, but just to add to your points:
Rot13(Gur 5 jvgu shyy zrzorefuvc jvyy nyyhqr gb gur 5 sbhaqvat fgngrf fgvyy va vg, Nhfgenyvn, Pnanqn, Arj Mrnynaq, Fbhgu Nsevpn, naq gur HX. Gur fuvryq ersref gb gur synt bs Xraln. Gur bar gung pneevrf n cvpgher bs uvzfrys vf Plcehf, nf gurve synt vf n cvpgher bs Plcehf ba n znc. Whavbe zrzoref cebonoyl ersref gb gur yvxrf bs Fpbgynaq, Jnyrf naq Abegurea Verynaq, jub pbzcrgr frcnengryl ng gur pbzzbajrnygu tnzrf.)

Comment: Hey, great advise! I had similar ideas, here's my reasoning: Fb V gubhtug bs Xraln, ohg ur fnvq lbh pna gryy ol gur fuvryq gung gurl ner abg fbyqvref, naq gurer ner gjb fcrnef oruvaq gur fuvryq, nyfb va ertneqf gb gur svefg uvag - gur Xralna synt qbrfa'g unir oyhr ba vg. Ur nyfb fnvq gung gur bar jub pneevrf n cvpgher bs uvzfrys unf qvfthvfrq vg jryy, naq Plcehf'f synt vf boivbhfyl n znc (nyfb ab oyhr). V qb guvax lbh'ir tbg n tbbq cbvag jvgu gur Pnanqn naq Fbhgu Nsevpn gurbevrf, gubhtu Pnanqn qbrfa'g unir n cvpgher bs gurzfryirf bs n fuvryq.

Comment: A lot of correct ideas here, but this is not the intended group.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be:

> England

And the group is:

> The British Isles

one of them carries a shield with him.

> Might be Jersey in the Channel Islands. Or the Welsh Dragon?

Another member carries a picture of himself with him, although it's pretty well disguised and at first glance you'd think that it's something else entirely.

> I think is Republic of Ireland, the flag is orange, green, and white, so might refer to a Leprechaun that has ginger/orange hair, white face, and green clothes.

Two of the others carry crosses, but don't think it's because they're religious. It's more of a symbol of where they're from than anything else.

> Scotland and Northern Island have diagonal crosses on their flags.

One of them has been thinking about leaving our little group

> There was a Scottish referendum about leaving the UK but they (closely) voted no.

<s>However,</s>

> <s>That leaves out Wales, so exact guessing of each clue may be wrong.</s>

Comment: Great answer! It’s possible too that the symbol on the flag of your however country represents the shield instead of the one you identified; I think you’re absolutely right that the second one ought to be included! I love the reasoning for the rest! :)

Comment: Except Ireland isn't part of the UK

Comment: @Mohirl I said rot13(Oevgvfu Vfyrf) which includes Ireland.

Comment: The north part is

Comment: Your symbolism interpretation for the second members symbol is pretty insulting (speaking as a native of that member). It’s also likely just wrong.

Comment: @illustro if it's wrong, then I'm just a stereotyping so and so (at least be happy I chose the creature to reference rather than the people), if it's right, blame the writer of the riddle :P

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> The United Nations, and Jackie is the UK

I wouldn't call myself our leader in any real sense, but I certainly am our oldest member. We used to have more members, but currently it's only five of us with full membership. In addition we have many junior members, most of whom are children of full members.

> 5 leaders of the UNSC, 5 founding members of the UN, junior members/children being ex colonies/freed states.

Now, some info about us. I won't bother describing myself – I'm pretty prominent so you're probably familiar with how I look like. I will say that I have a lot of children, and many of them are junior members in our group.

> The UK's former colonies, so children

As for the others, I'll tell you that one of them carries a shield with him. He's by no means a soldier, though, and you can tell that just by looking at his shield.

> possibly "The United States, whose shield contains olive branches, symbol of peace" From @SteveV's answer. Also possibly the French unofficial emblem which also features olive branches.

Another member carries a picture of himself with him, although it's pretty well disguised and at first glance you'd think that it's something else entirely.

> Possibly the PRC, The red and stars are all about the communist uprising, which certainly is a big part of their identity

Two of the others carry crosses, but don't think it's because they're religious. It's more of a symbol of where they're from than anything else. One of them has been thinking about leaving our little group, but I think he's decided to stay for now. It's his decision either way, of course.

> Possibly the UK for the different crosses of the individual countries, and maybe the crosses on the Russian coat of arms, for the imperial history of Russia

Comment: This is really well justified, but not the intended answer.